# Problem with audio file encoding for Twilio calls

Tags: php, encoding, twilio, html5-audio, phone-call

I’m having issues with recording audio files in the browser to use with Twilio. I basically copied the code from this ->
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API
for the recorder. What I want to do is save the audio file to my webserver, which is working, then send it to Twilio to make a call using it. The sample code from MDN creates a blob that is encoded as an OGG file, so I changed that line to this:

```
const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/wav' });
```

instead of this:

```
const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
```

Here is the code I'm using to send the audio file to Twilio using PHP:

```
$client->account->calls->create(
   $phoneNum,
   $twilio_number,
   [
      "twiml" => "<Response><Play>${audioClipPath}</Play></Response>"
      // audioClipPath is https://www.example.com/audio_files/filename.wav
   ]
);
```

So everything seemed to be working well, I have the file saving to the webserver properly, and the required access to the directory so that there’s no issue using that clip with Twilio. The only thing is Twilio keeps giving me an error when I try to access that file. Twilio will call my number but will say `We're sorry, an application error has occurred` and the Twilio debugger is giving me `Error - 11200 HTTP retrieval failure`.  I know for sure it’s not a directory permissions thing, because when I upload a music clip to the webserver it works just fine. So my thought is that I’m somehow encoding the audio file wrong and Twilio doesn’t like it. Does anyone have any experience with this issue or thoughts on how to move forward?

Oh I forgot to mention I’ve also tried `audio/mp3`, and `audio/wave` format as well.

Comment: Use a tool like Audacity, https://www.audacityteam.org/, to see what the actual encoding is. Something with the encoding is the issue.

Comment: Best Practices for Audio Recordings - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180588-Best-Practices-for-Audio-Recordings

Comment: @Alan I put the audio file into audacity and it wasn't a recognized format.  I'm currently recording using the MediaRecorder API but as I'm looking into encoding audio files it seems like there are a bunch of browser specific limitations.  Diving deeper seems like I'm getting sucked into an encoding black hole and I'm not familiar with any of these topics.  As such do you have any suggestions on how I can change the encoding form the MediaRecorder into the right format after it's been recorded?

Comment: Phil Nash wrote a blog, you need to transcode it to make it useful - An introduction to the MediaRecorder API - https://www.twilio.com/blog/mediastream-recording-api : If you download one of your recordings, you may find you don't have a media player that's capable of playing a WebM file. WebM is an open source format for both audio and video, but it's mostly had support from browsers. If you have VLC player you can likely play the audio, otherwise you might want to convert it to an MP3 or WAV file using an online tool like convertio (or if you're feeling daring, with ffmpeg in your terminal).

Comment: @Alan Thank you that article is extremely helpful.  I think I'm a glutton for punishment - so ffmpeg it is!!